# Translate multiple numbers enclosed within double quotes (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xslt-1.0

Is it possible to process a variable with multiple numbers enclosed within double quotes? Ie. Translate function in xslt 1.0 returns an error when I translate the quote to a period. A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of translate() ("2", "1", ”1”)

I would like (“2”,”1”,”1”) translated to (.2.1.1.)

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Project type="cim" version="0.1">
   <Projects>
     <WBSs> 
       <WBS GUID=”2”> 
         <WBSs>
            <WBS GUID=”1”>
             </WBS>
               <WBSs>
                <WBS GUID=”1”>
                </WBS>
              </WBSs>
            <WBS GUID=”2”>
            </WBS>
            <WBS GUID=”3”>
              <WBSs>
                <WBS GUID=”4”>
                </WBS>
              </WBSs>
            </WBS>
         </WBSs> 
       <WBS GUID=”4”>
          <WBSs>
            <WBS GUID=”5”>
            </WBS>
            <WBS GUID=”8”>
            </WBS>
            <WBS GUID=”2”>
            </WBS>
            <WBS GUID=”10”>
            </WBS>
         </WBSs> 
       </WBS>
     </WBSs>
   </Projects>
</Project>
```

xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="NETWORK ">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=".//WBS" mode="I_NETWORK">                
    <xsl:with-param name="ProjectId" select="$ProjectId"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="WBS" mode="I_NETWORK"> 
  <xsl:param name="ProjectId"/>

<xsl:variable name="wbsCode" select="@GUID"/>   
<xsl:variable name="quot">"</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="var1">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate($wbsCode,$quot,'.')"/>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You have to use the real double quotes in your XML, "2", rather than the curvy double quotes, “2”.  Once you have real double quotes in XML use the escape character to do your translate.  Your editor may be putting the curvy double quotes in.

<xsl:variable name="test">
  <xsl:value-of select="'(&quot;2&quot;,&quot;1&quot;,&quot;1&quot;)'"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="result">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate($test,'&quot;','.')"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize there were two sets of quotes.

Comment: I think the processor may have inserted the quotes during syntax check. When I look at the data, it is actually '2 1 1' (without the apostrophies)   So the quotes do not even appear. If I translate ' ' to '.', the translate function still fails because 3 items are being passed as the first argument.

Comment: You could also transform the curvy double quotes.  If you want to transfrom 2 1 1 to 2.1.1 you can transform the spaces to .  You may want to normalize-space first.  Or you could split the string and from that build what you want.  At, any rate, good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Bluewood66.  The normalize-space function also fails with " A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of
  normalize-space() ("2", "1", ...)" Splitting the string is probably the way to go.

Comment: http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_normalize-space.html   Put the string inside the parenthesis for normalize-space.   translate(normalize-space('my string 2'), ' ', '.')

Comment: I applied the same concept with string-join and got the result I was looking for.   <xsl:variable name="temp2" select="string-join(($test), '.')"/>                                       Thanks again @Bluewood66.